# Reference an External File/Sheet using a text string

Tags: microsoft-excel

Basically I have file 1 and file 2. File 2 has multiple sheets for each day named according to the date (THU 07 FEB, FRI 08 FEB, etc). Each of these sheets contain data appropriate to this day.

I want to use a text string in file 1 (entering "THU 07 FEB" into a cell) which will then reference the data from this sheet and display it in file 1. If I then change the text in the cell to FRI 08 FEB, it will bring up the data from this sheet instead.

If I was using the same spreadsheet I know I could use the INDIRECT function to do this but because its another file entirely, I'm not sure how I would do about doing this. Anyone can enlighten me? Thanks.

Edit: Hi all just to update on this I have managed to make the link using the following formula;

=INDIRECT("'["&M2&"]"&I2&"'!"&J4)

M2 = Spreadsheet, I2 = Sheet name, J4 = Cell

The only issue I have is the Spreadsheet reference is 'only' using the spreadsheet name, is there anyway to include the file path to this as shown below so that I dont require the file to be open to reference it(example);

S:\2. COMPANY\CONTROL TOWER\TEMPLATES

Answer (score 0):

file path, file name, sheet name, range is added in a function like this:

```
=COUNT('E:\Downloads\trial\[Book1.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1:A10)
```

Your formula would be

```
=INDIRECT("'"&P1&"["&M2&"]"&I2&"'!"&J4)
```

Where P1 would have your path like E:\Downloads\trial\ where M2 resides

or try directly putting path in the formula

```
=INDIRECT("'S:\DVY-ALL\2. MAST\CONTROL TOWER\["&M2&"]"&I2&"'!"&J4)
```

Comment: No, as I said above, all excel files that a formula refers to have to be open otherwise it will show err. So Indirect is not causing the problem.

Comment: Ah ok, so there is no way around this? To explain in more detail what im trying to do is basically, I have created a cell with a =TODAY() date in it and then another cell to change this date into a 'Thursday 07 February' format. The sheet names in the other file are named as so 'Thursday 07 February','Friday 08 February' and so on. The sheet name will change with the =TODAY() cell and will reference the data in that sheet on the other file and pull it to my table using the random cells I have listed (P23,P30,P34, etc).

Comment: I can, but the reason I would prefer not to is this is a quite a commonly used file in my operation, it is basically an overview sheet for picking and new picks are added to this sheet quite often. Hence why it would be nice to reference changes without it being open.

Comment: I have just found this formula could also be used to do what I want however; =INDEX('S:\DVY-ALL\2. MAST\CONTROL TOWER\[Call Off Daily Totals 2019.xlsx]"&I2&"'!P$1:P$50,6,1) The sheet name is the issue here, INDEX will pull the data while the file is closed but it cannot adapt the sheet name to change and I have tried this with "&l2&". This does not appear to be working, can you take a look at my formula and tell me if this is a no go or maybe I am just not referencing the cell with the sheet name correctly?

Comment: As it is a string concatenate formula, it should be enclosed fully in quotes (") at proper places, so that the formula is first solved to give the actual final string that Index() will use. So put " at the very beginning and " at the very end. Also end of path should have a \ before file name starts, so put a \ between TOWER\\[Call. So final string should be "'S:\DVY-ALL\2. MAST\CONTROL TOWER\\[Call Off Daily Totals 2019.xlsx]"&I2&"'!P$1:P$50" which results in 'S:\DVY-ALL\2. MAST\CONTROL TOWER\\[Call Off Daily Totals 2019.xlsx]'!P$1:P$50 reaching as the input of Index()

Comment: btw, as this site interprets \ as special escape character, it is possible that the site has removed the \ between TOWER\\[Call and you had put it correctly. Please check that only one single \ at the end of path before [