# How to use INDEX to reference another file using cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

So currently I have this question opened;

[Referencing an external file sheet using a text string](https://superuser.com/questions/1403165/reference-an-external-file-sheet-using-a-text-string)

To which we managed to work out how to reference cell data from another file/sheet using the INDIRECT formula and this was what I came out with;

```
=INDIRECT("'["&L2&"]"&I2&"'!"J4)
```

`L2` = Call Off Daily Totals 2019.xlsx (File name)

`I2` = Thursday 07 February (Sheet name - using TEXT formula dddd dd mmmm)

`J4` = `P34` (Cell I'm trying to reference)

Basically my sheet name (`I2`) is always changing as it references a `=TODAY()` cell, and the file I am referencing (`L2`) has each day in that exact format as the sheet names for each day, the cell (`J4`) changes once the day changes so for example when the day changes from Thursday to Friday, `J4` will reference cell `P34` in sheet name 'Friday 08 February' in my other file as opposed to Thursday because the file name changed with the day.

I have found out that the `INDIRECT` formula 'only' works while the file is opened and this is a bit of an issue to me as the file I am referencing is commonly used in my workplace and frequently updated.

I did a bit of searching and found `INDEX` works while the file is closed but the issue I have is, with `INDEX` I can write the whole string as;

```
=INDEX('S:\DVY-ALL\2. MAST\CONTROL TOWER\[Call Off Daily Totals 2019.xlsx]Thursday 07 February'!P$1:P$50,6,1)
```

And this works, but I need it to be able to reference `I2` instead of 'Thursday 07 February' as my date changes with each day. I tried this but it didn't seem to work;

```
=INDEX("'S:\DVY-ALL\2. MAST\CONTROL TOWER\[Call Off Daily Totals 2019.xlsx]"&I2&"'!P$1:P$50",6,1)
```

Anyone with knowledge of this or how I could go about it.

Comment: Well, you can't insert cell references into formulas without INDIRECT, so converting to INDEX and then trying to plug I2 back in just puts you back where you started.

Comment: If you're always doing the same thing accessing a cell for the day, have you tried using TODAY() in the INDEX? eg. `=TEXT(TODAY(),"dddd dd mmmm")`